# jquery code not executing from script, but executing from dev panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.henrybuilt.com/trade2/resource.php?id=100

Check out the link above. Login: asdf, asdf

EDIT: Click on bamboo on the link above once you've logged in. Thanks.

The following code (which toggles a 'popup' window (div)) won't execute on the page, but will work when copied and pasted in the dev panel.

```
            $(".maintypedata img").click(function() {
                console.log("test");
                if(open == false) {
                    var src = $(this).attr("src");
                    $(".popup").html("<img src='"+src+"'/>");
                    open = true;
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
                    $(".popup").slideFadeToggle(function() { 

                    });
                }
            });
```

How can I make it run from the script?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a document ready handler, or in a script block at the end of the body? You need that code to run _after_ the element(s) in question have been parsed. (And, nitpick: that code _doesn't_ toggle a window, it assigns a click handler. It's only when you subsequently click the img element(s) that the toggling happens.) By the way, I went to the site you linked to and didn't see any images to click on. If you expect us to try something out at an external site please provide complete instructions.

Comment: put it in a script tag at the end of the body

Comment: @nnnnnn - edited. and i have tried those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click handler you've shown is bound to any `".maintypedata img"` elements that exist *when that code runs.* But, the img elements in question are appended to the document dynamically after the "Bamboo" option is clicked. So you need to either run that `.click()` code after the elements are appended (which is what you were doing by running it from the console) or change it to work as a delegated event handler:

```
        $(".maintypedata").on("click", "img", function() {
            console.log("test");
            if(open == false) {
                var src = $(this).attr("src");
                $(".popup").html("<img src='"+src+"'/>");
                open = true;
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                $(".popup").slideFadeToggle(function() { 

                });
            }
        });
```

That is, bind the click handler to an element that exists initially, in this case `".maintypedata"`, but specify a selector in the second parameter to `.on()` and jQuery will only run your handler if the clicked item matches that second select at the time of the event.

(A delegated handler is also more efficient than binding the same handler to lots of separate elements, but that's just an added bonus.)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I edited my answer to change `$(document).on("click", ".maintypedata img",` to be `$(".maintypedata").on("click", "img",...` because it is more efficient to bind the handler to the lowest-level parent element that exists at the time.